# How to use to produce an array of odd integers from 2 to 30 using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm very new to Python and basic things are giving me trouble.

I tried using `np.arange(1,31,2)` but this obviously starts with 1 and if I begin with 2, I get even values.

I've also tried using functions but I'm unsure how to format them into arrays afterwards.

I'm new to data science and trying to learn. Also if this question isn't allowed, just delete it

Comment: You could start with 3.

Comment: You need to start from reading [documentation of numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). It says that third argument (non-keyword one) is the distance between two adjacent values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically ensure that the numbers are odd from an arbitrary start, you can use the modulo operator:

```
start = 2
stop = 30
a = np.arange(start+(start+1)%2, stop, 2)
```

output: `array([ 3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29])`